# Random numbers not changing

Tags: php, wordpress, random

I have written a simple page to test a problem with another part of a site I am developing.

Basically, variables are getting stuck for lack of a better term on certain systems.  I have inserted the following code into a wordpress page.

```
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion() . '<br>';
$timestamp = time();
$current_time = date('h:i:s');
echo 'Timestamp: ' . $timestamp . '<br /> Current Time: ' . $current_time . '<br />' ;
$randomA=mt_rand(1000,3000);
echo 'Random Number: '. $randomA . '<BR />' ;
```

This displays information of 3 different items that should change every time the page is loaded.

My problem is that systems on different places/isps/platforms are getting the same numbers every time the page loads.

If I load this page in chrome, safari or firefox on my mac I am getting an expected response.  If I attempt to load the page on my iPhone on the same wifi network as the mac, I always get the same numbers.

I have also tested the same code in a quick page on a separate server.  This other server always gives expected results on all devices.

I have attempted using unset and that did not work.

Comment: PHP is sever-side, so the end device should not matter. Random is as random does though. You could get the same number many times in a row. There is never a guarantee of it never being the same.

Comment: Yes, but should I be correct to assume that the time and timestamp should update?

Comment: Yep - and your code works for me. It could be a a caching issue possibly.

Comment: Could you check this link and let me know if it works?  http://www.mcoaeyecare.com/token-test/

Comment: That is working for me on a couple of devices. Do you want break caching?

Comment: @user2450091 fun fact. If you access the site like http://www.mcoaeyecare.com/token-test/?tok=somevalue and change the "somevalue" part each time, you get a new random number even with caching involved. It's probably a caching issue.

Comment: Wellllllllll, yes @apokryfos you will get a new random number - even if it is the same number. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've reproduced OPs issue before sharing the fun fact.

Comment: No doubt @apokryfos. That is why I asked if the OP wanted to break the cache. I was just sharing the fun fact that in a limited set of conditions you may return the same number from your random function each time because that is still random ;-)

Comment: Ok, is there a way to not cache a single variable?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your link. It is always giving same number.

Try using ob_clean and ob_flush.

Looks like the data is cached in server.

Comment: After further review, I've sound that there is Server level caching going on and that is causing my issue.  This is what happens when clients bring their own hosting to the table.  Stay away from GoDaddy Managed Wordpress Hosting!